# How to apply Java Stream for existing forEach loop with if condition

Tags: java, java-stream

I am new to Java stream and can use java stream on ArrayList. This time I don't have any clue and been trying since 2 hours. I am not getting any idea. I am not sure even if it is possible to use Java stream here. Can someone please guide me? I don't even know where to start. How shall I check for below condition `transactions.getAvatarInfo() != null`?

This for loop works as expected. and I need to use Java Streams here instead of for loop. I was able to use Java Streams at other for loops , it was straight forward. Here I don't even know where to start.

```
for (int i = 0; i < accountInfo.get().getTransactions().size(); i++) {

    Transactions transactions = accountInfo.get().getTransactions().get(i);
    AvatarInfo avatarInfo = new AvatarInfo ();
    if (transactions.getAvatarInfo() != null) {
        transations.setAvataruri(TransactionsConstant.PREFIX + 
            transactions.getAvatarInfo().getUserName().toLowerCase());
        transactions.getAvatarInfo().setUserName(transactions.getAvatarInfo ().getUsername());
    }
}
```

So far I have tried below but it gives error saying `; is expeccted` after null. And if I add that there would be another error.

```
accountInfo.get().getTransactions().stream().filter(a -> {
   AvatarInfo avatarInfo = new AvatarInfo ();
   a.getAvatarInfo() != null
})
```

Comment: Do you get an Exception? If so, can you add it to your question please?

Comment: This for loop works as expected. and I need to use Java Streams here instead of for loop. I was able to use Java Streams at other for loops , it was straight forward. Here I don't even know where to start.

Comment: You wouldn't want to do your processing in `filter` - that's just to filter the `Stream` and it returns another `Stream` for further processing (i.e. it's a "non-terminal operation").

That said, try limiting your current `filter` implementation to: `filter(Objects::nonNull)`


You're going to need to dig into the fundamentals of `Stream` API usage.

Comment: You can follow the `filter` invocation by putting your processing into a `forEach` method: `filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach( /* your data processing code here */)`

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: @BasilBourque, you are right, the title is weird. Fixed it now. I hope its OK now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only a single expression, you can write a lambda using just that expression, like this:

```
a -> (a.getAvatarInfo() != null) // returns a boolean for filter
```

However, when you introduce `{}`, you have a full embedded method that has to follow all the normal syntax for a method. In this case, since your lambda should return a boolean, you need

```
return a.getAvatarInfo() != null;
```

However, the `new AvatarInfo()` business appears to be completely unnecessary and can be removed, allowing you to use the simpler form.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is a `Collection`. Since Java 8 `Collection` defines a `stream()` method which will return a `Stream` of the elements of your `ArrayList`.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--

Answer (score 0):

To get the list we need a collector, so I think it should be like this:

```
transactions.stream()
            .filter(account -> account.getAvatarInfo() != null) 
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Otherwise it will only return a Stream instead of a List.

Comment: Yes but he first needs to process the items in the original `List`